# how to compare two audio samples that has been stored in a memory stream in c#

Tags: c#, audio, audio-streaming, naudio

I have been wondering as how to compare two audio samples hat have been copied to memory stream

I stored the sudio data using  :-      stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Now if I store another audio data in another stream then how can i compare the first audio stream and second audio stream to check if they are the same or not?

just like how one compares two words , I want to know how to compare two audio streams ? I will be really grateful if you can prove the code snippet.....Thanks in advance

Comment: When you read the stream, you will read it into a byte array. Why not compare them as byte arrays? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Mel frequency cepstral coefficients for this. I have been doing something similar to this with MFCCs and it worked. Get an auido feature extraction library with MFCC, get the MFCCs for both audio recordings which are 13 decimal values. After that calculate euclidean distance between the 13 MFCCs from the first audio and the 13 MFCCs from the second audio to see how near are they. You can have a distance limit, if the distance is larger than the limit than they are not the same audio recordings